# Can't successfully removeGestureRecognizer iOS

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a button in my iPad app, when its pressed it addGestureRecognizer's. When pressed again, its supposed to remove them.

My code is in an if block, and I know the right block of code is runned because NSLog print the right log message.

I'm adding the recognizers like this:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

And trying to remove them like this:

```
[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

This is my whole function:
http://www.pastelib.com/show/ZlICyb9Q

It does not work and I cant figure out why, do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for all the help and suggestions :)

Comment: when do you call which block -- what is self.view each time (NSLog(@"%@", self.view))

Comment: panRecognizer is an instance object?

Comment: This is my function: http://www.pastelib.com/show/ZlICyb9Q, NSLog self.view gives me the same each time: <UIView: 0x19c770; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x19c140>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GestureReconizers are declared locally to the -showMenu: method.
So each time your button is pressed, you create new GestureReconizers, so you didn't try to remove previous reconizers, but you try to remove newly created ones.

Change the scope of your reconizers objects, and your problem will be fixed.

Cheers.

Edit with code sample :

```
-(IBAction) showMenu:(id) sender {    
    if([self.view.subviews containsObject:menuView]) {

        NSLog(@"remove gestures!");

        // Dismiss menu
        [menuView removeFromSuperview];

        // Remove gestures
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];        
    }else{
        // Create menu        
        NSLog(@"add gestures!");

    panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];

    pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)];

    rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotationDetected:)];

    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];

     tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;    

     // Make gestures work simultaneously
     panRecognizer.delegate = self;
     pinchRecognizer.delegate = self;
     rotationRecognizer.delegate = self;

        // Set width and height if empty        
       self.menuController = [[menuController alloc] initWithNibName:@"menuController" bundle:nil];

        if(screenWidth == 0) {

            UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

            if(currentOrientation == 1 || currentOrientation == 2) {
                // portrait
                screenHeight    = self.menuController.view.frame.size.height;
                screenWidth     = self.menuController.view.frame.size.width;
            }else{
                // Landscape
                screenHeight     = self.menuController.view.frame.size.width;
                screenWidth    = self.menuController.view.frame.size.height+20; //height+20px for the status bar
            }
        }

        int menuHeight = 80;
        self.menuController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,screenHeight-(menuHeight-20), screenWidth, menuHeight);

        self.menuView = self.menuController.view;

        [self.menuController setDelegate:self];

        [self addChildViewController:self.menuController];
        [self.menuController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.view addSubview:menuView];


        // Add image gestures
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:menuButton];        

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem, and I learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

I did this in my project and it worked:

```
while (cellMainView.descripcionArticulo.gestureRecognizers.count) {
    [cellMainView.descripcionArticulo removeGestureRecognizer:[cellMainView.descripcionArticulo.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Comment: try
`for (UIGestureRecognizer * gesture in board.gestureRecognizers) {
        [board removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    }`